# Varnish expires header configuration

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, expires-header

Please help me in adding expires header in varnish configuration. max_age is already defined in vcl_fetch and  need to add expires header according to the max_age.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you do not need to set `Expires` header in addition to `Cache-Control`. The `Expires` header tells the cache (be it a proxy server or a browser cache) to cache the file until `Expires` time is reached. If both `Cache-Control` and `Expires` are defined, `Cache-Control` takes precedence.

Consider the following response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Fri, 14 Mar 2014 08:34:00 GMT
Expires: Fri, 14 Mar 2014 08:35:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
```

According to `Expires` header the content should be refreshed after one minute, but since max-age is set to 600 seconds, the image stays cached until 08:44:00 GMT.

If you wish to expire content at a specific time, you should drop the `Cache-Control` header and only use `Expires`.

Mark Nottingham has written a very good [tutorial on caching](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/). It's definitely worth reading when considering your cache strategy.

If you wish to set `Expires` header based on `Cache-Control: max-age`, you need to use inline-C in your VCL. The following is copied from https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleSetExpires in case the page is removed in the future.

Add the following prototypes:

```
C{
        #include <string.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        void TIM_format(double t, char *p);
        double TIM_real(void);
}C
```

And the following piece of inline-C to the vcl_deliver function:

```
C{
        char *cache = VRT_GetHdr(sp, HDR_RESP, "\016cache-control:");
        char date[40];
        int max_age = -1;
        int want_equals = 0;
        if(cache) {
                while(*cache != '\0') {
                        if (want_equals && *cache == '=') {
                                cache++;
                                max_age = strtoul(cache, 0, 0);
                                break;
                        }

                        if (*cache == 'm' && !memcmp(cache, "max-age", 7)) {
                                cache += 7;
                                want_equals = 1;
                                continue;
                        }
                        cache++;
                }
                if (max_age != -1) {
                        TIM_format(TIM_real() + max_age, date);
                        VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_RESP, "\010Expires:", date, vrt_magic_string_end);
                }
        }
}C
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `max-age` is already setted (i.e by your webserver), you can set Expires header with this configuration in your vcl :

```
# Add required lib to use durations
import std;

sub vcl_backend_response {

    # If max-age is setted, add a custom header to delegate calculation to vcl_deliver
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s) {
        set beresp.http.x-obj-ttl = beresp.ttl + "s";
    }

}

sub vcl_deliver {

    # Calculate duration and set Expires header
    if (resp.http.x-obj-ttl) {
        set resp.http.Expires = "" + (now + std.duration(resp.http.x-obj-ttl, 3600s));
        unset resp.http.x-obj-ttl;
    }
}
```

Source : https://www.g-loaded.eu/2016/11/25/how-to-set-the-expires-header-correctly-in-varnish/

Additional info : you can set `max-age` on your apache server with this example :

```
<LocationMatch "/(path1|path2)/">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
</LocationMatch>
```